# How to structure the class for this XML?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

How would I go about deserializing this XML into a class in C#?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<root>  
  <infos>  
  </infos>  
  <users>  
    <user userID="1" userRole="1" channelID="0"><![CDATA[Test_User]]></user> 
    <user userID="2" userRole="0" channelID="0"><![CDATA[Test_User_2]]></user> 
  </users>  
  <messages>   
    <message id="349992" dateTime="Sat, 01 Sep 2012 18:29:48 +0000" userID="1" userRole="1" channelID="0">  
      <username><![CDATA[Test_User]]></username>  
      <text><![CDATA[Test Message]]></text>  
    </message>  
    <message id="349993" dateTime="Sat, 01 Sep 2012 18:29:50 +0000" userID="2" userRole="0" channelID="0">  
      <username><![CDATA[Test_User_2]]></username>  
      <text><![CDATA[Test Message 2]]></text>  
    </message>  
  </messages>  
</root>
```

I've done a little serializing and deserializing with XML before, but for some reason I'm having trouble finding the correct structure for the classes with this XML.

So far this is about all I have and it doesn't work.
Could anyone structure these classes to work with the above XML?

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute("userID")]
    public object UserId;
    [XmlAttribute("userRole")]
    public object UserRole;
    [XmlAttribute("channelID")]
    public object ChannelId;
}

[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public object Id;
    [XmlAttribute("dateTime")]
    public object DateTime;
    [XmlAttribute("userID")]
    public object UserId;
    [XmlAttribute("userRole")]
    public object UserRole;
    [XmlAttribute("channelID")]
    public object ChannelId;
    [XmlElement("username")] 
    public object Username;
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public object Text;
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("infos")]
    public object Infos;

    [XmlElement("users")]
    public List<User> Users;

    [XmlElement("messages")]
    public List<Message> Messages;
}
```

It's throwing this error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=There was an error reflecting type 'ConsoleApplication.Client.Root'.

Message=There was an error reflecting field 'Users'.

Message=There was an error reflecting type 'ConsoleApplication.Client.User'.

Message=There was an error reflecting field 'UserId'.

Message=Cannot serialize member 'UserId' of type System.Object. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code and explain what is not working and where you are stuck.

Comment: Take a look at [`xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) - you can use it to generate an XSD file from the XML (though you may want to look it over and correct it if the assumptions made are not correct), then on the resulting XSD you can run it again to generate a C# class.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a poor description of the issue. Can you be more specific as to _what_ isn't working? Exceptions? Errors? What is the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour?

Comment: I've tried xsd.exe before posting and It just seemed to of generated 10KB of useless code.

Comment: Many of your `XmlElement` should be `XmlAttribute`. Do you know the difference between an Element and an Attribute?

Comment: Do I know the difference? No. I don't have much experience with Attributes.

Comment: I am talking about [XML Elements and Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0tkwcx.aspx). These are _basic_ things you need to know about XML (and HTML).

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. Thank you very much. I'll change my code and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't seem to help, and I know I'm still doing it wrong.

Comment: You have _way_ too many `XmlRoot`s - an XML file has _one_ root (in your case, the `root` element).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16141/discussion-between-bobby-and-oded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it with these classes. *Please be very careful as some changes have been **case sensitive**!*

```
// only one xml root element is allowed!
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {       }
    [XmlAttribute("userID")]
    public string UserId;
    [XmlAttribute("userRole")]
    public string UserRole;
    [XmlAttribute("channelID")]
    public string ChannelId;
}

[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public Message()
    {     }
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id;
    [XmlAttribute("dateTime")]
    public string DateTime;
    [XmlAttribute("userID")]
    public string UserId;
    [XmlAttribute("userRole")]
    public string UserRole;
    [XmlAttribute("channelID")]
    public string ChannelId;
    [XmlElement("username")]
    public string Username;
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public string Text;
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    public Root()
    { }

    [XmlElement("infos")]
    public object Infos;

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "user", Type=typeof(User))]
    public User[] users;

    // define what type message is - XmlArray
    // each item within is of c# type Message but within xml file it's message
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "message", Type = typeof(Message))]
    public Message[] messages;
}
```

Loaded data with

```
private void frmXmlDeserialize_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("import.xml");
        Root r = (Root)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }           
}
```